# Install node modules of mongo-express error of kerbros

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to install node modules of mongoexpress module. while running `sudo npm install` I get the following warning message. Though it is a warning message i wanted to understand what cause this warning and how to avoid it. I am using Ubuntu 14.04, Node 0.12.0, MongoExpress 0.21.0

Thanks in advance

```
sathish@sathish-Vostro-1540:~/Documents/mongo-express$ npm install
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@2.0.3: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible

> kerberos@0.0.19 install /home/sathish/Documents/mongo-express/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild) || (exit 0)

child_process: customFds option is deprecated, use stdio instead.
make: Entering directory `/home/sathish/Documents/mongo-express/node_modules/kerberos/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/worker.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberosgss.o
../lib/kerberosgss.c:36:0: warning: ignoring #pragma clang diagnostic [-Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma clang diagnostic push
 ^
../lib/kerberosgss.c:37:0: warning: ignoring #pragma clang diagnostic [-Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
 ^
../lib/kerberosgss.c: In function ‘authenticate_gss_client_wrap’:
../lib/kerberosgss.c:377:19: warning: variable ‘server_conf_flags’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   char buf[4096], server_conf_flags;
                   ^
../lib/kerberosgss.c: At top level:
../lib/kerberosgss.c:945:0: warning: ignoring #pragma clang diagnostic [-Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma clang diagnostic pop
 ^
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/base64.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos_context.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos.node: Finished
  COPY Release/kerberos.node
make: Leaving directory `/home/sathish/Documents/mongo-express/node_modules/kerberos/build'
basic-auth-connect@1.0.0 node_modules/basic-auth-connect

consolidate@0.12.1 node_modules/consolidate

underscore@1.6.0 node_modules/underscore

async@0.8.0 node_modules/async

serve-favicon@2.3.0 node_modules/serve-favicon
├── fresh@0.3.0
├── parseurl@1.3.1
├── etag@1.7.0
└── ms@0.7.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The npm modules that are installing contain a dependency on graceful-fs v3. And this will fail with newer versions of node. My guess would be that the mongoexpress team will have to update their dependencies in order to be able to compile on newer versions of node.

Hope this helps you :-)